# AccessToken.getScreenName() reutns null in twitter integration android

Tags: android, twitter

integrate twitter with my android app i successfully get the token and tokeSecreat but when i fetch the screen name of twitter it gives me null how to solve this.below is the AccessToken i get from the twitter

```
AccessToken a = new AccessToken(
httpOauthConsumer.getToken(),
httpOauthConsumer.getTokenSecret());
System.out.println("Urgntly"+a.getScreenName());

a.getScreenName() gives me null.how to get the ScreenName of Twitter userName.
```

Comment: after asking the question do you bother to come and check the answers given for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know whether you are using any API for Twitter or not.
But i have used [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) and done this way

```
        AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token, secret);
        final Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY,
                Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
```

and then using that twitter object

```
    try {
        twitter.getScreenName();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TwitterException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i dont find any method named twitter.getScreenName().i am using following library twiiter4j-core 2.1.0

Comment: yes the above code is for twitter4j you just make a Twitter object as above and you will get this..the above code is implemented in project and works fine..just once paste it in your proj

Comment: do you even bother to search in the documentation.. http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/index.html

Comment: yes i create the twitter as you mentioned but it not show any method which you mentioned twitter.getScreenName()

Comment: really?..can you post your code above? or just paste your whole activity code here and send me a link http://pastebin.com/ come to Casual Chat Room

Comment: I'm finding that Twitter.screenName == null after authorization is granted. Hence, getScreenName() is also returning null :-/  (note: I am using version 3.0.3)

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere The API is changed, you can download the latest version of Twitter4J and try with that new jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
        //Some information is available through method calls

        int myid=twitter.getId();

        String username=twitter.getScreenName();
```

username will return here://

Comment: I'm seeing `null` returned from `getScreenName()`. Is there a need for permission to read the user name (like facebook has) ? (Note: I am using lib ver 3.0.3)